# How to export a specific column data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table. I need to export all the rows for 1 column only. How can I achieve this? I know how to export the whole table but have not find a way to export a single columns data.

Comment: `select column_name from Table`?  What tool are you using to interface with MySQL

Comment: What do you want to do? To export to another table? Is another table on another server? Or do you want to export to another format - CSV, XML, Excel...?

Comment: I'm using Mysql workbench. I want to export the column data to csv file.

Comment: Then you can use SELECT statement with INTO OUTFILE option, that Jacob suggested.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This query should work(Use SELECT INTO OUTFILE 'file_name')-

```
SELECT `column` FROM `table` INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
```

Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: Your answer is working fine, but where exported file is save?
i want a file location

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_fields()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given got this error.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it very easily using MySQL GUI tools like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php), PHPMyAdmin. In [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) you just need to select the table, Click on "Export As..." Icon and you will get dialog to select the columns that you want to Export. Then click on "Export Button". Export is done...

Here is the screen shot showing export of column "city" in XML format.

Hope it helps...

[image: SQLyog Export As Screenshot]

Comment: Its in SQLyog, not in Workbench, You can use the links given in Answer to try SQLyog

Answer (score 4):

This is for mysql phpmyadmin

```
   select column_name from table_name
```

and result set will show now. you can see the tab `Query results operations Print view`  bottom of the page, the select the export and download which type you want.

Answer (score 2):

mysql database -e 'select field, field from table' | less

or into a file.

On unix it's working.

all the best

Answer (score 1):

try this..Each result data will be in each row with cell by cell

SELECT cu.*, cy.name as country_name, st.name as state_name FROM `table_name` cu, all_countries cy, all_states st where cu.country = cy.id and cu.state = st.id INTO OUTFILE 'file_info3.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\t\n'

The output file will be located at "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\db_name\".

Answer (score 1):

For workbench you can do it this way (I'm using MySQL Workbench version 6.3):

Right-click on the table and click on "Table Data Export Wizard" which will let you select the columns you want to export:

[image]

[image]

It exports as csv or json.

You can import it back the similar way. (Right-click on the table and click "Table Data Import Wizard"

Answer (score 1):

Solution from https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-mysqldump-to-export-individual-fields/4743 worked for me

```
mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE --execute='SELECT FIELD, FIELD FROM TABLE LIMIT 0, 10000 ’ -X > file.xml
```

I tried to export  data from a kubernet pod using following query and it worked for me

```
kubectl exec  podName -n namespaceName  -- mysql --host=hostName --user=userName --password=password dbName --execute=“SELECT FIELD, FIELD FROM TABLE LIMIT 0, 10000”> a5.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can write the sql select to the column you want to export.

```
SELECT [column_name] FROM [table_name]
```

and then you can scroll down to the "Query results operations" section.

[Query results operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnU5k.png)

then click **export**.